# How to Use Only One MVC Controller For Entire Application?

Tags: model-view-controller

```
Is it possible Single Controller for Entire MVC Application to Route Views Or can we Rename Controller Name at Run-time to Route Views?..
```

**i tried below code for route Views working fine.
controller:-**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult Commmon_Method(string VN, string Id)
 {
   return View(@"~/" + VN + ".cshtml");
 }
}
```

view page:

```
$('#btn_Test').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Commmon_Method", "Home")?Id=' + 1 + '&VN=' + 'Views/Test/Index2';
    });
```

**output URL:-**

```
http://localhost:52296/Home/Commmon_Method?Id=1&VN=Views/Test2/Index
```

-----------------------------*---------------------

**even though i tried myself like MVC based Dynamic Route but not able to succeeded:**

```
http://localhost:52296/Home/Test2/Index
```

so Controller Name should be single to supply all the request as well as i tried run-time Controller also and custom based Controller not succeed

one more thing i succeed single dynamic JSON Data method in MVC,so no need to write bundle of code to get JSON Data using Jquery Ajax method.

only thing in MVC, Single Controller based Routing Succeeded means MVC will be very Easy Development Apps, So can you Share your knowledge to Simplify the Complex Way of Development

Answer (score 0):

html :-

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=Test';
```

**Controller method to create Controller:**

```
public ActionResult common_dll(string ctrl)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("using System;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Collections.Generic;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Data;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Data.SqlClient;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Dynamic;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Linq;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Text;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Web.Mvc;" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("namespace Testing_MVC.Controllers" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("{" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("public class " + ctrl + "Controller" + " : Controller" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("{" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("public ActionResult Index()" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("{" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("return View();" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("}" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("}" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("}" + Environment.NewLine);

            var dir = Server.MapPath("~\\Controllers");
            var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, ctrl + "Controller" + ".cs");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, sb.ToString());

            return this.RedirectToAction("Index", ctrl, new { id = 1 });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string JS_NAS(DataSet dss)
    {
        string str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dss, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        return str;
    }

    public static SqlParameter[] NAS_SQLPRM(string paramstr)
    {
        #region
        string[] parameters = paramstr.Split('~');
        string err = string.Empty;

        int len = parameters.Length;
        SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            string[] paramWithValue = parameters[i].Split('$');            
        string param = paramWithValue[0].ToString();
            string value = paramWithValue[1].ToString();
            sqlParam[i] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = param, Value = value };
        }
        return sqlParam;
        #endregion
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static String Insertupdates(string paramstr, string procname)
    {
        string err = "", dbstr = "";
        string[] parameters = paramstr.Split('~');
        int len = parameters.Length;
        SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            string[] paramWithValue = parameters[i].Split('$');
            string param = paramWithValue[0].ToString();
            string value = paramWithValue[1].ToString();
            sqlParam[i] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = param, Value = value };
        }

        string str = new clsiCMSBLBase().insertData(ref err, ref dbstr, sqlParam, procname);
        return err.Replace("$", "") + "$" + dbstr.Replace("$", "");
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public static String GetRowData_Tables(string procedureName, string paramstr)
    {
        string[] parameters = paramstr.Split('~');
        string err = string.Empty;
        int len = parameters.Length;
        SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            string[] paramWithValue = parameters[i].Split('$');
            string param = paramWithValue[0].ToString();
            string value = paramWithValue[1].ToString();
            sqlParam[i] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = param, Value = value };
        }

        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new clsiCMSBLBase().GetListData(ref err, sqlParam, procedureName);
            String JSONString = String.Empty;
            JSONString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

            return JSONString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }


    var data = getRowData_TableBased('DBSP_ListSupplierGroup', paramstr);

function create_Listgrid(data) {
        var cellsrenderer = function (row, column, value) {
            return '<div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 5px;">' + (1 + row) + '</div>';
        }

        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: '98%',
            height: '370px',
            source: { datatype: "json", datafields: [], localdata: data },
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            theme: 'energyblue',
            pageable: true,
            columnsresize: true,
            pagesizeoptions: ['5', '10', '15', '20', '100'],
            pagesize: 15,
            pagermode: 'default',
            enabletooltips: true,

            columns: get_cols(data)
            /*
            columns: [
                        { text: 'S.No', dataField: 'Slno', align: 'left', width: '40px', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer },
                        { text: 'MapID', dataField: 'MapID', align: 'left', hidden: true },
                        { text: 'PriSupplierID', dataField: 'PriSupplierID', align: 'left', hidden: true },

                        { text: "Primary Supp Code", datafield: "PriSuppCode", cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: '140px' },
                        { text: "Primary Supplier Name", datafield: "PriSupName", cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: '420px' },
                        { text: "Primary Supplier Type", datafield: "PriSupType", cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: '125px', hidden: true },

                        { text: 'SecSupplierID', dataField: 'SecSupplierID', align: 'left', hidden: true },
                        { text: "Secondary Supplier Code", datafield: "SecSuppCode", cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: '190px' },
                        { text: "Secondary Supplier Name", datafield: "SecSupName", cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: '420px' },
                        { text: "SecSupType", datafield: "SecSupType", cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', hidden: true }
            ]
            */
        });
    }

    function get_cols(data) {
        var datacols = new Array();
        if (!isEmpty(data) && data.Table1.length > 0) {
            $.each(data.Table1, function (name, v) {
                if (v.ColumnWidth == 0)
                    datacols.push({ text: v.ColumnHeader, datafield: v.DataField, hidden: true });
                else
                    datacols.push({ text: v.ColumnHeader, datafield: v.DataField, cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: v.ColumnWidth });
            });

            $("#<%=btnExport.ClientID%>").show();
        }
        return datacols;
    }

function getRowData_TableBased(procName, paramstr) {
        var rowData;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Supplier_Group.aspx/GetRowData_Tables',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            data: "{procedureName: '" + procName + "',paramstr: '" + paramstr + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var response = data.d;
                if (response != "Error") {
                    rowData = $.parseJSON(response);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Retrive Error !!");
                }
            },
            error: function (error) { }
        });
        return rowData;
    }


    /*
    var paramstr = '';
    paramstr = "@UserID$" + uid + '~';
    paramstr += "@PageName$" + pgnm + '~';
    */
    paramstr += "@MethodName$" + pgnm + '~';
            paramstr += "@ErrorMsg$" + msg;



function fncCompareDates1(startDate, endDate) {
            startDate = startDate.split('/');
            endDate = endDate.split('/');

            var new_start_date = new Date(startDate[2], startDate[1], startDate[0]);
            var new_end_date = new Date(endDate[2], endDate[1], endDate[0]);


            var date1 = startDate.split('/')[2] + "-" + startDate.split('/')[1] + "-" + startDate.split('/')[0];
            var new_start_date = new Date(date1);

            var date2 = endDate.split('/')[2] + "-" + endDate.split('/')[1] + "-" + endDate.split('/')[0];
            var new_end_date = new Date(date2);

            if (date_format(startDate) > date_format(endDate))
                return false;

            return true;
        }


public static DataSet BIZ_LIST_DATA(ref string errString, SqlParameter[] parameters, string spname)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = DB_LIST_DATA(parameters, spname);
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errString = ex.Message;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static DataSet DB_LIST_DATA(SqlParameter[] Params, string spName)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(main.connectionStringICane());
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = spName;
            foreach (SqlParameter p in Params)
            {
                if ((p.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput) && (p.Value == null))
                {
                    p.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
            sqlCon.Dispose();
        }
    }



function get_cols(data) {
    var datacols = [];
    if (!isEmpty(data)) {
        $.each(data.Table1, function (name, value) {
            if (value.ColumnWidth == 0)
                datacols.push({ text: value.ColumnHeader, datafield: value.DataField, hidden: true });
            else
                datacols.push({ text: value.ColumnHeader, datafield: value.DataField, cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: value.ColumnWidth });
        });
    }
    return datacols;
}

function isEmpty(str) {
    return typeof str == 'string' && !str.trim() || typeof str == 'undefined' || str === null || str == 0 || str == "" || str == "[]";
}

function getRowData_TableBased(procName, paramstr, urlpath) {
    var rowData = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: urlpath,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: "{procedureName: '" + procName + "',paramstr: '" + paramstr + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            rowData = data;
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    });
    return rowData;
}

function Common_grid() {
    var commonModuleOption = {
        width: '97%',
        height: '350',
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        theme: 'energyblue',
        pageable: true,
        columnsresize: true,
        pagesizeoptions: ['5', '10', '15', '20', '100'],
        pagesize: 15,
        pagermode: 'default',
        enabletooltips: true,
    };

    return commonModuleOption;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Commmon_Method(string VN, string Id)
        {
            return View(@"~/" + VN + ".cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult Commmon_Method_Url()
        {
            return PartialView(@"~/" + Request.QueryString["VN"] + ".cshtml");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetRowData_Tables(string paramstr, string procedureName)
        {
            #region
            string[] parameters = paramstr.Split('~');
            string err = string.Empty;

            int len = parameters.Length;
            SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                string[] paramWithValue = parameters[i].Split('$');
                string param = paramWithValue[0].ToString();
                string value = paramWithValue[1].ToString();
                sqlParam[i] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = param, Value = value };
            }

            return Content(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetListData(ref err, sqlParam, procedureName), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
            #endregion
        }

        public DataSet GetListData(ref string errString, SqlParameter[] parameters, string spname)
        {
            #region
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = ListData(parameters, spname);
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errString = ex.Message;

            }
            return null;
            #endregion
        }

        public DataSet ListData(SqlParameter[] Params, string spName)
        {
            #region
            String conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection2"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conString);

            #region
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = spName;
                foreach (SqlParameter p in Params)
                {
                    if ((p.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput) && (p.Value == null))
                    {
                        p.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
                sqlCon.Dispose();
            }
            #endregion
            #endregion
        }

        //[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public ActionResult LoadMenus()
        {
            #region
            #region
            var cntent = "";
            DataSet dsmenus = new DataSet();
            string error = "";
            SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@usid", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 6 } };
            dsmenus = new DALModel().populateDataSet(ref error, parameters, "DBSP_Get_Menu");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            #endregion

            sb.Append("<ul id='main-menu' class='sm sm-vertical sm-blue' data-smartmenus-id='15544681331245752'>");
            if (dsmenus.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MenuID"].ToString() == "0" && dsmenus.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ParentID"].ToString() == "0")
            {
                cntent = "<ul></ul>";
            }
            else
            {
                #region
                var ds = dsmenus.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("ParentID") == Convert.ToInt32("0"));
                foreach (DataRow pdr in ds)
                {
                    var MenuID = Convert.ToInt32(pdr["MenuID"].ToString());
                    var Action = pdr["Action"].ToString();
                    var Controller = pdr["Controller"].ToString();
                    var MenuDesc = pdr["MenuDesc"].ToString();

                    sb.Append("<li>");

                    if (Action == "")
                        sb.Append("<a href='#'>" + MenuDesc + "</a>");
                    else
                        //sb.Append("<a href='" + Url.Action(Action, Controller, new { MenuId = MenuID }) + "'>" + "" + MenuDesc + "" + "</a>");
                        sb.Append("<a href='" + Url.Action("Commmon_Method_Url", "Home", new { VN = Action, ID = MenuID }) + "'>" + "" + MenuDesc + "" + "</a>");

                    sb = getSubMenuList(MenuID, dsmenus, sb);
                    sb.Append("</li>");
                }
                #endregion
            }

            sb.Append("</ul>");
            cntent = sb.ToString();
            return Content(cntent, "text/html");
            #endregion
        }

        [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public StringBuilder getSubMenuList(Int32 ParentID, DataSet ds, StringBuilder sb)
        {
            #region
            try
            {
                var sm = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("ParentID") == ParentID);
                Int32 cnt = sm.AsDataView<DataRow>().Count;
                if (cnt > 0)
                {
                    #region
                    sb.Append("<ul>");
                    foreach (DataRow subdr in sm)
                    {
                        var MenuID = Convert.ToInt32(subdr["MenuID"].ToString());
                        var Action = subdr["Action"].ToString();
                        var Controller = subdr["Controller"].ToString();
                        string MenuDesc = subdr["MenuDesc"].ToString().Replace(" ", "-");

                        sb.Append("<li>");
                        if (Action == "")
                            sb.Append("<a href='#'>" + MenuDesc + "</a>");
                        else
                            //sb.Append("<a href='" + Url.Action(Action, Controller, new { MenuId = MenuID }) + "'>" + MenuDesc + "</a>");
                            sb.Append("<a href='" + Url.Action("Commmon_Method_Url", "Home", new { VN = Action, ID = MenuID }) + "'>" + MenuDesc + "</a>");

                        sb = getSubMenuList(MenuID, ds, sb);
                        sb.Append("</li>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</ul>");
                    #endregion
                }
                else
                {
                    return sb;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return sb;
            #endregion
        }

        public ActionResult common_dll(string ctrl, string View)
        {
            #region
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("using System;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Collections.Generic;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Data;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Data.SqlClient;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Dynamic;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Linq;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Text;" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("using System.Reflection;" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("using System.Reflection.Emit;" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("using System.Web.Mvc;" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("namespace Testing_MVC.Controllers" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("{" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("public class " + ctrl + "Controller" + " : Controller" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("{" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("public ActionResult " + View + "()" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("{" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("return View();" + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("}" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("}" + Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append("}" + Environment.NewLine);
            #endregion

            #region
            var dir = Server.MapPath("~\\Controllers");
            var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, ctrl + "Controller" + ".cs");

            /*
                System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
                System.IO.StreamWriter str = fi.CreateText();
                str.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                str.Close();
            */

            //System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, sb.ToString());

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);

            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(file, sb.ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).ToList<string>());

            /*
                System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
                System.IO.StreamWriter str = fi.CreateText();
                str.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                str.Close();
            */
            #endregion

            return this.RedirectToAction(View, ctrl, new { MainID = 12, ID = 1 });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#btn_Test').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=Testing&View=Index';
        //window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Commmon_Method", "Home")?Id=' + 1 + '&VN=' + 'Areas/Testing/Views/Index';
    });
</script>

<script>
    //$(function () {
    //    var paramstr = '';
    //    paramstr = "@@Month$" + 1;
    //    paramstr += "~@@Year$" + 2018;
    //    paramstr += "~@@StateID$" + 0;
    //    paramstr += "~@@HubID$" + 0;
    //    paramstr += "~@@BranchID$" + 0;
    //    paramstr += "~@@EmpID$" + 0;
    //    paramstr += "~@@EmpTypeID$" + 0;
    //    paramstr += "~@@UserID$" + 1;
    //    paramstr += "~@@UserTypeID$" + 1;

    //    var data = getRowData_TableBased('DBSP_MM_Rpt_AttendanceMonthWsie', paramstr, '@Url.Action("GetRowData_Tables", "Home")');
    //    Grid(data);
    //});

    function Grid(data) {
        if (!isEmpty(data)) {
            //$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid($.extend(true, {}, Common_grid(), {
            //    source: { datatype: "json", datafields: [], localdata: data },
            //    columns: Get_Colmns(data)
            //}));
        }
    }

    function Get_Colmns(data) {
        var datacols = [];
        if (!isEmpty(data)) {
            $.each(data.Table1, function (name, value) {
                if (value.ColumnWidth == 0)
                    datacols.push({ text: value.ColumnHeader, datafield: value.DataField, hidden: true });
                else
                    datacols.push({ text: value.ColumnHeader, datafield: value.DataField, cellsalign: 'left', align: 'left', width: value.ColumnWidth });
            });
        }
        return datacols;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#btn_Controller1').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=Testing&View=Index';

        //window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Commmon_Method", "Home")?Id=' + 1 + '&VN=' + 'Views/Test/Index';
        //window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=List&View=Index';
    });

    $('#btn_Controller2').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=MyDocs&View=Test';
    });

    $('#btn_Controller3').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=Test&View=Delete';
    });

    $('#btn_Controller4').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=Test1&View=Index';
    });

    $('#btn_Controller5').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=Test2&View=Index';
    });

    $('#btn_Controller6').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("common_dll", "Home")?ctrl=Test3&View=Index';
    });
</script>
```